# Can't escape apostrophe

Tags: javascript, c#

I'm having some trouble escaping an apostrophe in the following javascript code that I am pushing through my webbrowser.

Here is the code that I am using:

```
tempString1 = "building\'s";
wvMain.EvalScript("frames['main'].document.getElementById('txtInstructions').value='" + tempString1 + "';");
```

I get this error:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected indentifier.

I have tried doing:

```
tempString1 = "building" + Convert.ToChar(34) + "s"; //I get the same error
```

And this:

`&#39;` gets copied directly into the textfield itself.

does anyone have any advice?

Comment: Use a template literal and circumvent the whole issue.

Comment: that code is syntactically valid (just pasted it into an online checker to see what the problem was), so whatever problem is being highlighted isn't with those lines

Comment: You're building the following and evaluating it: `frames['main'].document.getElementById('txtInstructions').value='building's';` And that's not valid...

Comment: good point @JoeDyndale, I see the problem now - you need to escape the backslash in the definition of `tempString1`: `tempString1 = "building\\'s";`. But the real question here is why on Earth are you a) building up strings of code in such a dirty way and b) (more importantly), `eval`ing things in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is with the joining of string in with the second line. It is evaluating to `frames['main'].document.getElementById('txtInstructions').value='building's';`
So you will need to add '\' in front of the apostrophe in order to eval correctly.

```js
   tempString1 = "building\\'s";
wvMain.EvalScript(`frames['main'].document.getElementById('txtInstructions').value='${tempString1}';`);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can escape the value before putting it into your script:

```
tempString1 = "building\'s";
let tempStringLiteral = `'${tempString1.replace("'", "\\'")}'`;
wvMain.EvalScript("frames['main'].document.getElementById('txtInstructions').value=" + tempString1 + ";");
```

But I'd recommend looking into the `EvalScript` method's documentation to see if there's not a more reliable way to pass arguments into it that can be used by the script you give it.

Answer (score -2):

Escaping is unnecessary when you are using double quotes

`tempString1 = "building's";`

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem. The problem is with having the apostrophe in the text in the first place. It's not entirely clear what the end goal here is.